# Add blank columns in MDX query

Tags: mdx, cross-join

How to add blank columns in MDX Query?

I have tried all possible options such as adding member and all, but when I am trying to cross join the new member, i get MDX errors. Please guide me through this.

Thanks

We need following MDX format and need blank columns in the MDX Query

[image: Required MDX format]

My current MDX is

```
WITH
SET [PL_AsOfDate_XXX] AS
    Distinct(
        Hierarchize({
            [AsOfDate].[ALL].[AllMember].[31-05-2013], [AsOfDate].[ALL].[AllMember].[30-05-2013]})
    )
SET [PL_AsOfDate_XXX2] AS
    Distinct(
        Hierarchize({
            [AsOfDate].[ALL].[AllMember].[31-05-2013]})
    )
MEMBER [Book].[Books] AS
    Aggregate({[Book].[ALL].[AllMember].[YYY], [Book].[ALL].[AllMember].[ZZZ]})
SELECT
NON EMPTY DrilldownLevel({[LBook].[ALL].[AllMember]}) ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {Crossjoin({[Measures].[1D]}, [PL_AsOfDate_XXX]), Crossjoin({[Measures].[10D]}, [PL_AsOfDate_XXX2])} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ([Book].[Books], [Type].[Type].[TOTAL])
```

Answer (score 0):

With 
Member Something as 1+1
member BlankColumn1  as null
member BlankColumn2  as null
member BlankColumn3  as null
Select (
{
 Something,
 BlankColumn1,
 BlankColumn2,
BlankColumn3 
}) 
on columns
 from [UKM Trading]